# Unable to split the string by the dates

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to split the text right after each dates. I was trying with the below code. But it is give me the string itself.

```
string[] split = Regex.Split("SEND MILK EVERYDAY FOR THIS PERSON FROM 02/10/2014 TO 02/11/2014  SKIP 03/11/2014 AND 09/11/2014", @"^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$")
```

Looking for a output like

```
SEND MILK EVERYDAY FOR THIS PERSON FROM 02/10/2014
TO 02/11/2014
SKIP 03/11/2014
AND 09/11/2014
```

Comment: Why is `AND 09/11/2014` not expected?

Comment: What are you getting from your current regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry that was my bad. I just corrected the question

Comment: Well, it still looks complicated, but it is working: [`(?<=\b(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/-](?:0?[1-9]|1[012])[/-]\d{4}\b)\s*(?!\s*$)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cb%28%3f%3a0%3f%5b1-9%5d%7c%5b12%5d%5b0-9%5d%7c3%5b01%5d%29%5b%2f-%5d%28%3f%3a0%3f%5b1-9%5d%7c1%5b012%5d%29%5b%2f-%5d%5cd%7b4%7d%5cb%29%5cs*%28%3f!%5cs*%24%29&i=SEND+MILK+EVERYDAY+FOR+THIS+PERSON+FROM+02%2f10%2f2014+TO+02%2f11%2f2014++SKIP+03%2f11%2f2014+AND+09%2f11%2f2014). Or `Regex.Split(s, @"(?<=\b(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/-](?:0?[1-9]|1[012])[/-]\d{4}\b)\s*").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))`

Comment: @TrippKinetics the string itself

Comment: Or, [`Regex.Matches(s, @"(?s).*?\b(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/-](?:0?[1-9]|1[012])[/-]\d{4}\b").Cast<Match>().Select(x=>x.Value)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=.*%3f%5cb%28%3f%3a0%3f%5b1-9%5d%7c%5b12%5d%5b0-9%5d%7c3%5b01%5d%29%5b%2f-%5d%28%3f%3a0%3f%5b1-9%5d%7c1%5b012%5d%29%5b%2f-%5d%5cd%7b4%7d%5cb&i=SEND+MILK+EVERYDAY+FOR+THIS+PERSON+FROM+02%2f10%2f2014+TO+02%2f11%2f2014++SKIP+03%2f11%2f2014+AND+09%2f11%2f2014)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Its working. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

string[] split = Regex.Split("SEND MILK EVERYDAY FOR THIS PERSON FROM 02/10/2014 TO 02/11/2014 SKIP 03/11/2014 AND 09/11/2014", @"(?<=\b(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/-[/-]\d{4}\b)\s*(?!\s*$)");

Answer (score 0):

You may try this regex to split,

```
(?<=\d{4})\s+
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C%2F%5Cd%7B4%7D%29%5Cs%2B&i=SEND%20MILK%20EVERYDAY%20FOR%20THIS%20PERSON%20FROM%2002%2F10%2F2014%20TO%2002%2F11%2F2014%20%20SKIP%2003%2F11%2F2014%20AND%2009%2F11%2F2014),,,  in which you can see split points